# Rewrite C++ function to C# (pass pointer to next element in array)

Tags: c#, c++

I need to rewrite this C++ function to C#

```
bool DesDecrypt(const BYTE *InBuff, DWORD dwInBuffSize, BYTE *OutBuff, DWORD dwOutBuffSize, const char *TerminalID)
{

...

for(DWORD i = 0 ; i < dwInBuffSize/8 ; i++)
        DES.des_ecb_encrypt((des_cblock *)InBuff+i, (des_cblock *)OutBuff+i, sched, DES_DECRYPT) ;


}
```

The place I am stuck is pointer arithmetic. On C++ side you can see author uses

```
InBuff+i
```

So it is advancing pointer and passing it to function.

On C# my function looks like this:

```
public static bool DesDecrypt(byte[] inBuff, uint inBuffSize, byte[] outBuff, uint outBufSize, string terminalID)
{
.....
}
```

I am stuck how to rewrite above loop(particularly how to pass pointer to next element in byte array) to C#. In C# there is no pointer arithmetic so if I do similar, it will just pass i'th value of byte array.

**So how can I simulate on C# passing pointer to the next element in array ?**

This is my decrypt function in C#

```
public static byte[] DecryptDES_ECB(byte [] ciphertext, byte [] key)
```

which I should use instead of C++  version:  `DES.des_ecb_encrypt`

---

I am looking for such wrapper as a solution on C# side

```
 public static byte[] DecryptDES_ECB(byte[] ciphertext, int cipherOffset, byte[] key)
    {
        byte [] tmp = new byte [ciphertext.Length - cipherOffset];
        for(int i = 0; i<ciphertext.Length - cipherOffset; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = ciphertext[cipherOffset + i];


        }
        return DecryptDES_ECB(tmp, key);
    }
```

Do you think this should work? Now I will call this function on C# side in loop and pass offset as in C++.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but assuming `InBuff` and `OutBuff` are pointers to the first element in the array (`index = 0`), then `InBuff+i` would exactly result in the `i`-th element. However if it is reasonable to assume, that InBuff and OutBuff point at an arbitrary point in their arrays, you would need to additionally pass an `offset`-parameter in your C#-function.

Comment: @LorToso The problem is my C# decrypt function also takes byte array as parameter

Comment: @LorToso: Please see update

Comment: Of course your updated solution would work. Consider using Array.copy() instead though (which is probably optimized to a c-call of memcpy() and should be a lot faster)

Comment: @LorToso Thanks but if you like my solution I will use it :)

Comment: It's a normal solution.

Comment: @LorToso: Hm you can see there is OutBuff similarly also on C++ side, what to do with that?

Comment: @PavelRudko: Hm you can see there is OutBuff similarly also on C++ side, what to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a LINQ extension and write `inBuff.Skip(i)` you will get an IEnumerable that yilds it's elements starting with the i inBuff element. Unless you call `ToList` method no copying and additional memory allocation will appear but you can treat and use your new IEnumerable like it's a subarray.

Answer (score 0):

After your update:

Easiest solution would be to get some sort of subarray of your inBuff and outBuff, then perform your `DecryptDES_ECB()`-function and copy your results into your original arrays afterwards.

```
public static void DecryptDES_ECB(byte[] ciphertext, byte[] decryptedtext, int cipherOffset, byte[] key)
{
    byte [] tmpCipher = new byte [ciphertext.Length - cipherOffset];
    Array.copy(ciphertext, cipherOffset, tmpCipher, 0, tmpCipher.Length);
    byte [] tmpDecrypt = DecryptDES_ECB(tmp, key);
    Array.copy(tmpDecrypt, 0, decryptedtext, cipherOffset, tmpDecrypt.Length);
}
```

This method has **not** been tested and I don't know the underlaying library, so I can not guarantee for correctness. But generally this would be an easy (but rather slow) attempt on solving your general problem.

EDIT:
Just some additional info on [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1): It performs a `memmove` which internally (usually) performs a call to `memcpy`, which is pretty damn fast. (Usually) a lot faster than your loop can possibly be.